# TypeScript or ( | ) not allowed and must use any to override

Tags: angular, typescript

so I have this interface:

```
export interface IPrivileges {
    $: IPrivDetails;
    Groups: Array<IGroup> | IGroupPriv;
}

interface IGroupPriv {
    Group: Array<GroupCollection>;
}

export interface IGroup {
    Group: GroupCollection[];
}

interface IPrivDetails {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export interface GroupCollection {
    $: GeneratedType18;
    Tables: any[];
}
```

and when I do:

```
console.log(businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups.Group);
```

getting an error of:

```
Error:(159, 88) TS2339: Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'IGroup[] | IGroupPriv'.
  Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'IGroup[]'.
```

I was under the impression the `|` in `Groups: Array<IGroup> | IGroupPriv;` will solve it but I have to use `any` as in `Groups: Array<IGroup> | IGroupPriv | any;` to override

any ideas how to get rid of any?

thanks

Sean

Comment: `IGroup[] | IGroupPriv` means it could be either, but by calling `.Group` that means you're assuming it's a `IGroupPriv`. You will need to type check to determine which of the two it is.
Also `| any` isn't what you want, since it just turns the entire type into `any`

Comment: I know, thus I posted this question :)

Answer (score 4):

the other answers are correct that the `|` creates a union type that means it could be either type and you must let TS know which type it is before treating it as one type or the other (the exception being common properties / methods).  You could use type assertions as others have shown if you're confident in the type, or you can be a bit more safe and check the type with a type guard:

```
function isGroupPriv(g): g is IGroupPriv {
  return !!g.Group;
}
```

which can be used as such:

```
if (isGroupPriv(businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups)) {
  // ts is now aware of the type of `privilegeInfo` inside this block scope
  console.log(businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups.Group);
}
```

or in this case you can actually use an in built array typeguard and TS will be smart enough to figure it out:

```
if (!Array.isArray(businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups)) {
  // ts is now aware of the type of `privilegeInfo` inside this block scope
  // as it knows if it's not an array, it must be IGroupPriv
  console.log(businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups.Group);
}
```

Comment: Your first snippet will still raise the same error, as you're trying to access the Group property on type 'IGroup[] | IGroupPriv'. It does not matter that you're doing so in a condition.

Comment: it worked in earlier TS versions, been removed, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

As Mingwei Samuel pointed out in his comment, you've declared `Groups` as `Array<IGroup> | IGroupPriv`. That is literally *either* an array of `IGroup` objects *or* a single `IGroupPriv` object.

The way to handle this situation is not with type assertions or introducing `any`, but by leveraging the idiomatic techniques to distinguish between arrays and scalars that are present in JavaScript and recognized by TypeScript.

This functionality is provided by JavaScript, for example by `Array.isArray` which is understood by TypeScript such that the natural JavaScript pattern for testing if a value is an array guides the TypeScript type system.

```
type GeneratedType18 = {
  _: 'x';
}
export interface IPrivileges {
  $: IPrivDetails;
  Groups: Array<IGroup> | IGroupPriv;
}

interface IGroupPriv {
  Group: Array<GroupCollection>;
}

export interface IGroup {
  Group: GroupCollection[];
}

interface IPrivDetails {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface GroupCollection {
  $: GeneratedType18;
  Tables: any[];
}
declare const businessUserInfo: { privilegeInfo: IPrivileges };
const privilegeGroups = businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups;

// idiomatic runtime test -> TypeScript recognizes and propagates
// to each branch of the ternary expression.
const groupCollections = Array.isArray(privilegeGroups)
  ? privilegeGroups.flatMap(g => g.Group) // TypeScript knows Array<IGroup>
  : privilegeGroups.Group;                // TypeScript knows IGroupPriv

console.log(groupCollections);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBDYEAmAVcECMAHFALxQDeAsAFBRQD6AXFAOQAezA3NQL7UStgA9kmBQAlvHRIAZigDG0AJIAFJGIBuYgDYQA5hADO5arQAkTFWvUARCMBTaDXGrCSCArmANMAgklQgADyKMG6eAHxQAD5QIWFgqhrOvFTUElKyCrGhHglWxi45nr7+KEFFYADCglo6csBigvDhydR8AsKi6ciZShUFtBVMFdW1EPWN8ADaALqtqVTdMvJKiTZ2DlpGlC5iGEwGwGrwus608CgAthAHRxKnPG1U-EIi4pI9K665o3UNTQMoOZYAhkGhMDhIIQzlAsCgAEY6bxQFDwECzeYYcZaFBIaByJqHKDw9wGCSGAwAVQMyEU8GkgiYZCgYCs2j0EDpDIsa3Z+iM3GcBPgRNZGj5EAqRlIJLJiAMVJpSC5ggAdGLNDp9CrVVLnNQAPQG8QYRqXNBiORQJDuSRia5QdBEgC0kUhEAAynI1GBRHiCbp4GIAF6GFHwDAstxgFC6cEGQ3G4CCKAQeQAC2JqHgckzgmkjvT0CkFyQIFTAjxCsmquowqJuniv3G-xFJCgfgCqrEBk7ZQAFBqJVKAJQmKAAfij4q1kviBlV0hxwAAsigwP3dCRIrpdfER1AjbDcF6faIANbwQQAdyMfaCcVy4XHTCHs6le9yHFoP9-f9oR7uqeYi+lAl43kYj6eGsTz1jUECqlogi6JuTY1H8kwGCO+oLGIBb9ve3a9qUICDmy77ziOB47ABxpAd6IEXlet4diRwQVM+LgMkgUD9vWohbvm06ahyo6ArQcE6IhyGbp+njYeOKQpBAWzQDRh50SeDGgeBLFQXkGjjpJCFIShb6ifOclgApVDcEAA)

In the above, I've used a ternary expression to extract the group data depending on whether the object is an array or not. This works in any other conditional context. For example, in an `if..else`

```
if (Array.isArray(privilegeGroups)) {
  // TypeScript knows Array<IGroup>
  for (const g of privilegeGroups) {
    console.log(g.Group);
  }
}
else {
  // TypeScript knows IGroupPriv
  console.log(privilegeGroups.Group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Groups property in IPrivileges is a union type, and can be expected to reliably resolve only properties common to both Array and IGroupPriv at runtime. Property 'Group' does not exist on the array type, hence the error. If you're confident that businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups will resolve to IGroupPriv at runtime, try

```
console.log((businessUserInfo.privilegeInfo.Groups as IGroupPriv).Group);
```

Comment: You're  just ignoring the types. If the types are wrong, they should be fixed. If the types of correct, you're going to either encounter a runtime error or subtle bug depending on how the values are used

Comment: My answer relies on their confidence on the type at runtime, as stated. It is intended to minimally explain the cause of the error, and how it can be atomically addressed, without going into details which may be specific to their implementation.

Comment: This doesn't address the error. Why did he declare the type as a `X | Array<Y>` if he knows for sure that isn't the case. He also did not state that he had this assumption.

Comment: As for your question, bad design is more common than I'd like to admit. I do agree that he did not state the particular assumption I used in my answer, which is why the last statement in it starts with "If".

Comment: Sorry, this is bad code and bad advice. It's the wrong way to handle the situation even in pure Jabsence of TypeScript and the whole point of TypeScript is to catch mistakes like via type declarations like the one in the OP.